# How to properly convert a Request attribute to a Model attribute

Tags: laravel

Let's say I have an API that receives this JSON structure:

```json
{
    "operatingSystem": "Windows"
}
```

As we only have 3 major operating systems, I will use constants to associate their values

```php
protected $operatingSystem = [
    'Windows' => 1,
    'Linux' => 2,
    'Mac' => 3,
];
```

My database doesn't have a column named operatingSystem, only operatingSystemId. So I must convert my request:

```php
$newRequest = [
    'operatingSystemId' => $this->operatingSystem[$request->get('operatingSystem')],
];

MyModel::create($newRequest);
```

Is there some right way to convert my JSON request in some Reverse-resource-like Laravel utility?

Comment: Write a custom cast? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing your request, you can use [mutators in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to do your operation before storing it in the database or getting it from the database.

By `setter` methods, you can get an input variable (that send to store) and change it to custom format to store in database.

For example in your case, you should define a `setOperatingSystemIdAttribute()` method in your model with this body:

```
public function setOperatingSystemIdAttribute($value){
  $this->attributes['operatingSystemId'] = $this->operatingSystem[$value];
}
```